# iOS Private API Documentation

Tags: ios, ios4, documentation, iphone-privateapi

Is there a web site or project documenting private APIs for the iPhone SDK?

Comment: As much as this question is off-topic, it still is a favorite of many! :) Net votes +46, +38 favorites, in 5 yrs - 50K views and last active 2 months ago!

Comment: There are bunch of ready made dudes to mark something off-topic or down vote a question. They just can't handle anything.

Answer (score 38):

here are searchable archives from iPhone OS 2.2.1 to iOS 9.2

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers

Comment: This is probably the most up-to-date site, but it doesn't include C based frameworks, for example GraphicServices.Framework, etc. Obvious since the runtime only finds Objective-C things :)

Comment: It is having all up to date headers, but it doesnt have that much documentation as required, so, not able to use it perfectly, actually dont know how to use any of them

Answer (score 20):

Most likely. Just use the command line application `class-dump` to view the private headers. Note that your app will be rejected from the App Store for linking to private frameworks if you link at compile. It is easy enough to see that you are linking the private frameworks by running `otool` on your binary if linked at compile.

Comment: but what if i dont want to put my app on appstore, is there any documentation for using private apis?

Answer (score 11):

These are the compilable headers generated by [class-dump-z](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/wiki/class_dump_z), a iOS class dumper:
http://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks

Comment: Ya, that is having all headers, but question here is for getting documentation for that

Comment: Apple's SDK is not open source, and no one has bothered to reverse engineer and document more than a few classes. So headers are all there is.

Answer (score 1):

You might also find my "private-dumper" ruby gem useful: http://rubygems.org/gems/private-dumper