# Private api's list

Tags: iphone, iphone-privateapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS Private API Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150360/ios-private-api-documentation)

Is there any link available that gives the list of private api's used in iPhone. My objective is to access the SMS, calendar, audi, video's from non jailbroken iPhone. I searched in the following link , but could not find any related informations.
[link text](http://ericasadun.com/iPhoneDocs300/files.htm)

Best Regards,

Mohamed Sadiq

Answer (score 1):

There's PrivateFrameworks folder in the same level with "public" Frameworks folder for a  start (`/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks)`. Although there's no headers available there at least you can see the list of them.

Comment: I got the private api's and added it to my code. BUt all teh api's are  undcoumented and could not find the usage of those api's . There were 100 of header files available. Is there any good llink or ebooks available that gives the documenation of all the private api's.

Sadiq

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these:

[iOS Private API Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150360/iphone-private-api-documentation)

http://aralbalkan.com/2106

Answer (score 0):

The Private API's are the Undocumented API's, because it is still in construction they can be changed or updated in future. so Apple rejects apps using Priate API's.