# Where can i find iOS 4.2 Private Frameworks Headers?

Tags: iphone, ios-4.2

The title self explains i think..

I found those: https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks
But doesn't seems to be 4.2...

Comment: PS: I've already try with class-dump but i get errors or incomplete headers.

Comment: What do you mean by "private" frameworks? any example?

Comment: All the frameworks in /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks
For example iTunesStore.framework, JSON.framework ecc..

Comment: You do know that if you use those, you can't submit your app to the App Store, right? Just making sure you understand that (I know there are alternative distribution mechanisms out there).

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Private API Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150360/ios-private-api-documentation)

Comment: @Marc W Yes, i know that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Bullocks. Thanks for this thread. Was just drooling over those frameworks myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tags