# Where can I find information about private iPhone APIs?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to make an iOS application **not for the App Store** involving customized screen savers, automatic starting and ending of phone calls, and contact restrictions. I have not been able to find resources and information regarding private, undocumented APIs, however. Does anyone have a pointer?

Comment: Perhaps you can't find it because it's *private* and *undocumented*...

Comment: There has to be some way, because when looking at "Cydia" store, these kind of applications are already available.

Comment: [iOS Private API Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150360/ios-private-api-documentation)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know something which is exposed via Objective C - you can look at https://github.com/rpetrich/iphoneheaders (or generate them yourself via class-dump-z)
Many private frameworks are here.

You also should look at http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Main_Page 
If you need access to undocumented C APIs and can't find examples...well,your only way in this case is IDA Pro

Answer (score 0):

This is never required, but if you want to do this then this is simply done like testing your app on your iPhone.

Just create an app in the developer account, add your iPhone, get development certificate & provisioning profile then install app directly to your iPhone.

Comment: my question wasn't about how to install and run application into device.