# What abilities do enterprise apps have over publicly distributed apps in iOS?

Tags: ios, enterprise

I believe I recall that "Enterprise" apps had permission to access a wider set of abilities than publicly-distributed apps. Are these documented anywhere? I know the distribution mechanism is different, but are there any additional APIs or app permissions or abilities beyond what a normal app is capable of?

I'm looking for a broad description, not a list of API interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

There is no diference, but you don't have to follow apple guidelines because Enterprise apps don't go throug the apple validation, so you can use "private APIs", background tasks, etc.

The only advantage I see is, you can download the .ipa from a web

Comment: Agreed.  
[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150360/ios-private-api-documentation) is the link to SO question about the list of private APIs

Comment: Since I am generally unfamiliar with the API methods that _are_ public, what, really, can I do with the private ones, safely?

Comment: Here you have the private frameworks https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks